# Keeping deep structure with rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an array / object tree like

```
a = [
  {x: 1, y: 2},
  {x: 22, y: 11}
]
```

And I want to iterate over the entries and call a rest service to add x and y and create a node result:

```
a = [
  {x: 1, y: 2, result: 3},
  {x: 22, y: 11, result: 33}
]
```

I have had success with forkJoin and other to get an observable of results Observable<Number[]> but haven't figured out how to do the forkJoin in such a way that it has the context to put it back into the tree in the right place.

```
const results: Observable<Number[]> = from(a).pipe(
  mergeMap(calcArray =>
    forkJoin(
      calcArray.map(calc => 
        this.mathService.add(calc.x, calc.y)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The example is simple and the reality is a bit more complex, but that is the gist of it. It seems like such a fundamental thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the result from the call to mathService looks like but I am assuming that it is a single integer. r is the result from a single call so modify `result: r` to match your actual response.

```
combineLatest(a.map(calc => this.mathService.add(calc.x, calc.y))).pipe(
  map(results => results.map((r, i) => ({ ...a[i], result: r })))
)
```